# load jquery mobile into java string

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

this is kinda stupid question but i have to ask it and taking risk of alot of neg piont.

for some offline use in android i need to load jquery mobile into a string, **BUT** in the middle of it there is `[^\/*]`, and java take the rest of code as comment.

what i tried?

tried alot of source for jquery mobile but all of them has this char in middle of it.

tring to scape `/*` but i couldn't find anything to do it.

how can i solve this?

EDIT:

I putted the file in asset and load it like this:

```
String jqMobile = loadFromAsset("js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js");

public String loadFromAsset(String name)
    {
        try
        {
            InputStream is = mContext.getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(name);
            int size;
            size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();

            String str = new String(buffer);

            return str;

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you put it in double quotes and escape all the double quotes and backslashes that are already inside it?

Comment: If i put that in string, the long string error raise during compile. So i puted that into a file and then read it as stream and copy it into string.

Comment: So... how about showing us the code?

Comment: please see the edited question, i load the jquery like this then add my jquery code then the browser show me this as text, but if i use the original jquery (not the mobile one) every thing is fine.